# Declaring functions in JSP?

Tags: jsp, function

I come from PHP world, where declaring a function in the middle of a php page is pretty simple.
I tried to do the same in JSP:

```
public String getQuarter(int i){
String quarter;
switch(i){
    case 1: quarter = "Winter";
    break;

    case 2: quarter = "Spring";
    break;

    case 3: quarter = "Summer I";
    break;

    case 4: quarter = "Summer II";
    break;

    case 5: quarter = "Fall";
    break;

    default: quarter = "ERROR";
}

return quarter;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred at line: 20 in the jsp file: /headers.jsp
Illegal modifier for the variable getQuarter; only final is permitted return;
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't do this. Pass the data in a usable form to the JSP from wherever you are getting it.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You need to enclose that in <%!  %> as follows:

```
<%!

public String getQuarter(int i){
String quarter;
switch(i){
        case 1: quarter = "Winter";
        break;

        case 2: quarter = "Spring";
        break;

        case 3: quarter = "Summer I";
        break;

        case 4: quarter = "Summer II";
        break;

        case 5: quarter = "Fall";
        break;

        default: quarter = "ERROR";
}

return quarter;
}

%>
```

You can then invoke the function within scriptlets or expressions:

```
<%
     out.print(getQuarter(4));
%>
```

**or**

```
<%= getQuarter(17) %>
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Adam, why shouldn't you? Please explain, please.

Comment: just in case anyone like me wanders what is the difference between <%! %> and <% %> there is a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508753/difference-between-and

Comment: @ericso You shouldn't because doing it this way is hard to debug, etc.; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1 for more info

Comment: Declare public static functions in the proper class, and if you need functions because of hierarchy/modularity or structural reasons then put it in a separate JSP, and include that. In the latter case, parameters can be passed on with `request.setAttribute(String, Object)` and `request.getAttribute(String, Object)`. If you still think that you need to declare functions in JSP, then think again why you are using JSP in the first place.