# Are methods legal inside JSP scriptlet?

Tags: java, jsp, methods, scriptlet

I know its not recommended, and I should be using tag libraries etc etc.

But I'd still like to know if it is legal to declare methods in a JSP scriplet:

```
<%
   public String doSomething(String param) {
      //
   }

   String test = doSomething("test");

%>
```

Is that legal? I am getting some weird compile errors (like `a ; is expected`) that don't seem to fit. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring functions in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826932/declaring-functions-in-jsp)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to use declaration syntax (`<%! ... %>`):

```
<%! 
   public String doSomething(String param) { 
      // 
   } 
%>
<%
   String test = doSomething("test"); 
%>
```

Answer (score 17):

**Understand the working of jsp** :The entire JSP is converted to a Java class by Tomcat. This Java class is nothing but the Servlet. So it is the servlet that you will be running at the end.

Now **consider** that you are writing a Jsp code that prints the sum of 2 nos,passed in a method

```
<body>
  <%!               
  public int add(int a,int b)           
          {                                     
    return a+b;
          } 
   %>

  <% 
  int k;                
      k=add(5,6);
  %>

  <%=                   
      k                     
  %>

</body>
```

So if you were to write the same code that prints out sum of 2 nos in a servlet, you would probably write that in doGet() method.

The **reason** why you would get an error is you are defining a method within another method (which violates the rule of method definitions).

**Hence we put the method in the definition tag so that if forms a new method**