# What is the difference between <%! %> and <% %> in JSP?

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

What is the difference between `<%! %>` and `<% %>` in JSP?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`<%! %>` are [JSP Declaration tags](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaos.html) while `<% %>` are [JSP Scriptlet tags](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html).

Any code you put in scriptlets gets put in the JSPs `_jspService()` method when it's compiled (the analogue of a Servlet's `doGet`, `doPost`,... methods). This is what you'd usually write your Java code in.

But what if you want to declare new methods in your JSP class or declare instance variables? That's when you'd use the declaration tags. Any thing you put in there gets put into the JSP, *outside* of the `_jspService()` method.

Comment: Hi, does this have anything to do with local variables vs intstance variables?

Comment: @Scicare Sorry, I was still editing the answer - does the update answer your question?