# JSP Current URL

Tags: java, jsp, uri

From some other posts, I was able to get the current URI via:

```
<%= request.getRequestURL() %>
```

However the following doesn't work:

```
<%! String foo = request.getRequestURL(); %>
```

I'm curious why the above doesn't work, and how to assign the current URI to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()), `getRequestURL()` returns a `StringBuffer`, not a `String`.

Try this instead:

```
String foo = request.getRequestURL().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting this, I found out how to make it work. The following code work:

```
<%
    StringBuffer foo = request.getRequestURL();
%>
```

I need to do some research to see what the difference between `<%` and `<%!` is.

Comment: For difference between `<%` and `<%!` read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508753/difference-between-and