# How to remove blank data?

Tags: java, jsp

I am displaying data as per product specification or as per it's configuration.

Configuration display left side of page. When user select configuration the related data should be filtered.
I have made category of attribute like Screen Size, RAM, HDD, Color, Size, Processor, optical drive etc.
And under it I am displaying data like 2GB, 4GB, 2.2GHz, Blue, 320GB etc.
[image]

But My problem is All Category display, if it's sub data exist or not.
I don't want to display category if sub data not exist like `Screen Size` is blank then it should not be display.

My JSP Code :

```
<%
            List<String> attribNameList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("attribName");
            List<String> attribValueList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("attribValue");
            List<String> attribDataList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("attribData");
            List<Integer> acfIDList = (List<Integer>)request.getAttribute("attribacID");

            List<Integer> acIDList = (List<Integer>)request.getAttribute("acID");
            List<String> acNAMEList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("acNAME");


            String aname,aval,adata,acname;
            Integer acfid,acid;

            for( int i=0;i<acIDList.size();i++)
            {
                acid=acIDList.get(i);
                acname=acNAMEList.get(i);
                //Print Category
                %>
                    <a style="color: black;"><%= acname %></a><br>
                <%

                for(int i1=0;i1<attribNameList.size();i1++)
                {
                    aname = attribNameList.get(i1);
                    aval = attribValueList.get(i1);
                    adata = attribDataList.get(i1);
                    acfid = acfIDList.get(i1);                          

                    if(acid == acfid)
                    {
                        //Print Attribute
                        %><br>
                            <%-- <a><%= aname %></a> &nbsp; --%>
                            <a><%= aval %></a> &nbsp;
                            <%
                                if(adata == null)
                                {

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    %>
                                        <a><%= adata %></a>
                                    <%
                                }

                    }
                }
                %>
                <br>
                <% 
            }

        %> 

Here `acIDList` is a attribute category id and `acnameList` is category name list and `acfIDList` is a `foreign key` in attribute_master table so I have put a if condition that when `acID` and `acfID` matches it creates List and under it sub data display.
```

and `aval` is attribute value that is `2,4,2.2, etc.` and `adata is for GB, GHz, MP, etc.`

So I want to remove `acName` that is blank.

I dont want to display category name if data not exist so shall I have to put some condition on

```
<a style="color: black;"><%= acname %></a><br>
```

line.
Any suggestion Please..

Comment: change the if condition if(acid == acfid) to if(acid == acfid && !aval.equals(""))

Comment: Just a side remark, in order to get a maintainable application consider to separate the view (i.e. jsp) from the application logic.

Comment: I think check the if(acid-- acfid &&!aval.isEmpty() && !aname.isEmpty())

Comment: @Neha - I don't want to display main category Name i.e. acName if sub data not exist so i don't think that your suggestion is correct, my update of question see at last in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you try logic this way .. to solve your issue..

```
for( int i=0;i<acIDList.size();i++)
        {
           int acid=acIDList.get(i);
            acname=acNAMEList.get(i);
            //Print Category                
            int i = getIndex(acid);
       if(i != -1)              
       {        aname = attribNameList.get(i);
                aval = attribValueList.get(i);
                adata = attribDataList.get(i);
                //Print full data 
      if(!aval.equals("")) //add your cond to check empty ..
          {  %>
                <a style="color: black;"><%= acname %></a><br>
              <%
                    %><br>
                        <%-- <a><%= aname %></a> &nbsp; --%>
                        <a><%= aval %></a> &nbsp;
                        <%
                            if(adata == null)
                            {         /*add you msg or html in case of null*/                   }
                            else //here all html with content and design
                            {  %>   <a><%= adata %></a>
                                <%
                            }
                }  }
            %>   <br>   <% 
        }
```

This you can define above or any server util class ..

```
 function int getIndex(int acid) 
{
    for(int i1=0;i1<attribNameList.size();i1++)
            {
                if(acid == acfIDList.get(i1))
                { return il; }
            }
    return -1;      
}
```

Comment: What about the below snippet of code ? where I ll have to use it ?

Comment: U need to write html inside the cond .. of if(!aval.qquals("")) {} ..and if you asking about getindex() you can define in jsp <% %> at start of jsp. refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826932/declaring-functions-in-jsp

Comment: and use i already mention in code -- int i = getIndex(acid); this gives the index number of ur matched acid .. for this index u running loop .. take out this index separate than check any cond on the values of subctagory (index)..

Comment: How `getIndex` will work without any return type ? shall I have to give it a return type like `Integer`, etc.

Comment: obviously and i modified it 17 mins ago with comment that i forget to write it..+ i edited my ans too..

Comment: It gives me error under `int` in function declaration that `invalid assignment operator` and at end `getIndex(acid)` that `insert ; to complete statement.`

Comment: Ok let me try it and inform you if i ll face any problem. I ll inform you soon.

Comment: now more errors under `int` and `Integer` and after argument under Integer it shows misplaced constructs.

Comment: its generic issues of programming .. its Integer class is not comparable to int .. so declare the Integer acid; -> int acid; .. and change the method signature to function getIndex(int acid)..

Comment: I try to give idea.. these general programming basic issues you should try to resolve urself.. :)

Comment: now it shows that ; expected on both side of argument means braces. it shows when i remove int as return type.

Comment: where can I share a code ? on stackoverflow or on your mail account or anywhere else ?

Comment: I have tried to put code inside <%!%> tag then error gone and 2 error remain that attribNameList can not resolved and remove int from declaration that is used as argument.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42842/discussion-between-java-curious--and-neha)

Comment: Hello are you there ? I got a problem.

Comment: I have added my problem to chat.

Comment: Hello, will you see this once : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520014/how-to-give-different-id-to-textbox-run-time/20520151?noredirect=1

Comment: Hello, I have put a checkbox with each data attribute and want to filter data as per attribute I have almost done it but I a getting single problem that all acID are sent to servlet, I just want to send acID of checkbox which ae checked. Any suggestion please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43096/discussion-between-java-curious--and-neha)

Answer (score 1):

Change your If condition as below

```
if(adata != null)                                
{
    %>
    <%-- <a><%= aname %></a> &nbsp; --%>
    <a><%= aval %></a> &nbsp;
        <a><%= adata %></a>
    <%
}
```

Put your `aname` printing inside your if clause.

Also to remove `acname` printing add if condition as below.

```
//Print Category
if (attribNameList.size() !=  0
    %>
        <a style="color: black;"><%= acname %></a><br>
    <%
}
```

So your final code should look like something.

```
String aname,aval,adata,acname;
Integer acfid,acid;

for( int i=0;i<acIDList.size();i++) {

    ....
    ....

    //Print Category
    if (attribNameList.size() !=  0)
    { 
    %> 
      <a style="color: black;"><%= acname %></a><br>
    <%      
    }
    for(int i1=0;i1<attribNameList.size();i1++) {
      ....
      ....

      //Print Attribute
      if(adata != null)        
      {
      %>        
        <a><%= aval %></a> &nbsp;
        <a><%= adata %></a>             
      }
      %>
    <br>
<% 
}
%>
```

Comment: I don't want to display category name so I have to put                    `<a style="color: black;"><%= acname %></a><br>` in condition ?

Comment: Edited the reply. Just add a condition while printing `acname`

Comment: Sir I am not getting you actually what you want to tell ? @ where I ll have to use `attribNameList` condition code ?

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ please find edited reply. Didn't want to spoon feed also, Learn how to check conditions in Java and JSP.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I got this correct, but if you need to omit blank\null values, you can use the

```
<c:if test="${CONDITION}">
</c:if>
```

tag