# cant create method in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I dont have too much experience with JSP. But i dont know why this code fails.

```
<%

String palabra=(String) request.getAttribute("expd");
System.err.print(palabra);
String fec=(String) request.getAttribute("fecha");
System.err.print(fec);
public  String contarCaracteres(String pa){

}

%>
```

Illegal modifier for the variable contarCaracteres; only final is permitted.

Anyone can help?? Probably i need several imports of java in my jsp, but i dont  know who classes import of java to prevent the error. Thx

Comment: Its failing in the method

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against scriptlets. They are not a good way to organise your Java code. JSTL is a good approach to get around this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring functions in JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826932/declaring-functions-in-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a JSP page as one giant "main" method that executes all the statements inside of it. So effectively what you are trying to do is
create a method inside another method, which is not allowed. However you can do so if you separate it in its own block, like here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/CreatingaMethod.htm

Answer (score 0):

All the code you include in a scriptlet `<%...%>` goes to the  `_jspService()` method of the class created from the JSP. The `public` identifier cannot be used with an automatic variable (the ones that are declared in a method) like `contarCaracteres`. For a quick solution remove the `public` modifier. However, probably it would be a good idea to include all this code on a Java bean.